# How i can subtract minimum value from sum value by the same order, article and different operation

Tags: c#, sql

Here is the example how it looks like. I'll like that to do in stored procedure, but i have confusion how i can detect new operation and subtract by minimal value.

```
  SELECT order_name, 
         article_name, 
         operation, 
         SUM(qty_pack) AS Controled, 
         SUM(repaired) AS Repaired
    FROM table_PrintJob 
   WHERE scanned = '1' AND 
         date_time BETWEEN @start_time AND 
         @end_time 
           --CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_time, 110)>=@start_time AND 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_time, 110)<=@end_time 
GROUP BY order_name, 
         article_name, 
         operation
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your example code ?

Comment: Hi, please post the code here, as code. That way it's easier for us to give the answer you seek.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN()` as a window function:

```
SELECT order_name, article_name, operation,
       SUM(qty_pack) AS Controled, SUM(repaired) AS Repaired,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY order_name, article_name) > 1
             THEN SUM(qty_pack) -
                  MIN(SUM(qty_pack)) OVER OVER (PARTITION BY order_name, article_name)
             ELSE SUM(qty_pack)
        END) as massaged_value
FROM table_PrintJob 
WHERE scanned = '1' AND
      date_time BETWEEN @start_time AND @end_time 
GROUP BY order_name, article_name, operation
```